# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Slow Upload Speed - RTL8111G

Tags: networking, 16.04, upload

The upload speed should be approx 38.60 Mbit/s. I have plugged another computer into the same LAN port and that machine gets an upload of 38.60 Mbit/s.

Slow Machine:
- Hardware = Realtek RTL8111G (MSI H81M-E34 Motherboard)
- speedtest-cli results = Download: 44.51 Mbit/s | Upload: 5.58 Mbit/s
- ufw is enabled (have tried turning it off but it has no effect on the results)
- uname -a = Linux 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your ISP? Most of them throttle uploads to prevent us from running servers at home, depending on what kind of account you have.  Comcast throttles uploads to approximately the value you mention.

Comment: Have confirmed it's not the ISP. The speedtest results are what i'm using as the main reference here. If i plug the slow machine into any of the other LAN ports i have available it gets the same, slow upload of approx 5Mb. All other machines get around 40Mb upload.

Comment: I wasn't sure from the wording in your question if you were uploading to another PC vs the internet.  Sounds like you have indeed ruled out the ISP.